# Pocket PC SQL Server connection error

Tags: c#, sql-server, pocketpc

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server 2005 via Pocket PC project in Visual Studio 2005. But I cannot.

When I try connecting via Windows Form application everything is ok. But in PocketPc application I am not able to connect. I think it is about connection string. Here are the strings;

```
connectionStr = @"Data Source=MUSTAFATOKNB\MTOKSQL;Initial Catalog=A1DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa; Password=mtok6878";
connectionStr = @"Data Source=MUSTAFATOKNB\MTOKSQL;Initial Catalog=A1DB;User ID=sa;Password=mtok6878;";
connectionStr = @"Data Source=MUSTAFATOKNB\MTOKSQL;Initial Catalog=A1DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=sa;Password=mtok6878;";
```

None of them is working in PocketPc but all of them work on Windows form application.

And idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your SQL Server (any directory on the network) using Windows Explorer first. It will ask you for your username and password to access the network resource.

Once Windows can connect to that resource, the connection string should work.

[image: screenshot1] [image: screenshot2]